# Find out which certificate authorities do not come with the system

Tags: keychain, ssl

I believe that some of the programs I downloaded in the past have installed some root certificate authorities on my Mac (the OS is Mavericks). After learning more about SSL/TLS, I figure that this is a security risk and I want to fix it. How do I distinguish these CAs from the ones preinstalled with the OS so that I can get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of trusted roots in Mavericks can be found here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6005

However, I'm not actually aware of a way to modify the "System Roots" keychain, so any new certificate authorities installed would appear in either the System or Login keychains.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the reverse engineering method.

Here is the [list](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11360) of all aps that come with Mac.

So any CA you find in key chain that are not those are the one you are looking for.